# Is there a built-in way to convert an argument-free function into a generator?

Tags: python, generator

Suppose I have a function which produces a value, say:

```
import random

def f():
    return random.randint(1,10)
```

Elsewhere in my program, I want to iterate over a sequence of values produced by this function:

```
def g(n):
    while True:
        if n == k:
            return
        else:
            print("x")
            return
```

Using the `while True` statement seems inelegant, and I would prefer to use a generator, like the following:

```
def f2():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(1,10)

def g(n):
    for k in f2():
        if n == k:
            return
        else:
            print("x")
```

However, this just pushes the issue of the `while True` into the definition of `f()`. Is there a built-in function which takes in a function and returns a generator, like the following pseudocode:

```
def make_generator_from_function(f):
    def gen_f():
        while True:
            yield f()
    return gen_f

def g3(n):
    for k in make_generator_from_function(f):
        if n == k:
            return
        else:
            print("x")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function can do this:

> If the second argument, `sentinel`, is given, then `object` must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call `object` with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()` method; if the value returned is equal to `sentinel`, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

Example: the number `5` is the sentinel, so the iteration will stop when `random.randint(1, 10)` returns `5`.

```py
>>> import random
>>> def f():
...     return random.randint(1, 10)
... 
>>> iter(f, 5)
<callable_iterator object at 0x7f3e11becc50>
>>> for x in iter(f, 5):
...     print(x)
... 
3
3
1
10
9
7
9
6
10
10
9
7
7
3
2
7
2
3
```

Comment: Is there an argument for the sentinel which is never matched? `None`, perhaps?

Comment: Any value that the function can't return will work; `None` is fine if your function returns numbers, as in this example. If your function might return `None`, then a common idiom is to use `object()` to create a fresh object that nothing else can equal.

Comment: It still feels a shame that Python is making an additional comparison to a dummy object every cycle of the iteration when the intent is for the comparison check to fail every time.

Comment: It seems like the C source code for it will do `sentinel == value` rather than `value == sentinel`, meaning it looks for `__eq__` on the sentinel, not on the value returned by `f`. So for `object()` there should be minimal overhead because `object.__eq__` is implemented in C.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) in a generator expression like:

#### Code:

```
import itertools as it
import random

for i in (random.randint(1, 10) for _ in it.repeat(1)):
    if i == 5:
        break
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
6
4
1
```

Comment: I did discover this right after posting the question, but it feels a shame for the cycle method to be carefully passing the list `[1]` over and over to itself when it will just be discarded.

Comment: `it.repeat(1)` is equivalent to `it.cycle([1])`, and since you're ignoring the results, `it.count()` would work too.

Comment: @Phro, the list would not be repeatedly passed to `cycle` as cycle stores the list, but repeat is a better alternative anyways.